# Try to connect nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to construct a structure of network (a diagram).
I use the following commands:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex’]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw=red, thick, ellipse,fill=red!20, minimum height=8em];
\matrix [column sep=6mm,row sep=10mm]
{
% row 1
 & &
\node [block] (init) {Lack of information}; &
 \\
% row 2
& & & & & \\
% row 3
& &
\node [block] (identify) {Perceptions about Nato's presence}; & \\
% row 3
\node [block] (update) {Positive perceptions}; &
& & &
\node [block] (evaluate) {Negative perceptions}; & \\
% row 4
 \node [block] (decide) {Desirable presence}; &
& & &
\node [block] (evaluate) {Non-desirable presence}; & \\
% row 5
& & & & & \\
% row 6
\node [block] (stop) {Efficient presence}; & 
\node [block] (stop) {Useless presence}; &
\node [block] (stop) {Service to others’ interests}; &
\node [block] (stop) {No institutional role}; &
\node [block] (stop) {Inefficient presence}; &\\
};
%arrows
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

My problem is I do not know how to connect with a line some of my nodes.
I tried to use the command:
\pathline--(); but it does not work.

What is the false?

Thank you in advance

Comment: welcome to tex.se! where should be lines? try `\draw (<node name 1>) -- (<node name 2>);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! There are a few options to draw the arrows:

1. `\draw[line] (init) -- (identify);` will draw a line of style `line` from the node `init` to `identify.
2. Alternatively, `\draw (identify) edge[line] (update);` will draw a line of style `line` from the node `identify` to `update.
3. If you get sick of always specifying the style, you could draw the edges in a scope with `every edge/.style={line}`.
4. In order to be able to draw arrows to all nodes, you need to give them unique names. However, you named a bunch of nodes `stop`.

Here is a code which follows the conventions of this site: it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled. Please consider posting such documents in the future.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,
  text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners},
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
  cloud/.style={draw=red, thick, ellipse,fill=red!20, minimum height=8em}}
  \matrix [column sep=6mm,row sep=10mm]
  {
  % row 1
   & &
  \node [block] (init) {Lack of information}; &
   \\
  % row 2
  & & & & & \\
  % row 3
  & &
  \node [block] (identify) {Perceptions about Nato's presence}; & \\
  % row 3
  \node [block] (update) {Positive perceptions}; &
  & & &
  \node [block] (evaluate) {Negative perceptions}; & \\
  % row 4
   \node [block] (decide) {Desirable presence}; &
  & & &
  \node [block] (evaluate) {Non-desirable presence}; & \\
  % row 5
  & & & & & \\
  % row 6 : give nodes uique names
  \node [block] (stop1) {Efficient presence}; & 
  \node [block] (stop2) {Useless presence}; &
  \node [block] (stop3) {Service to others' interests}; &
  \node [block] (stop4) {No institutional role}; &
  \node [block] (stop5) {Inefficient presence}; &\\
  };
  %arrows
  \draw[line] (init) -- (identify);
  \draw (identify) edge[line] (update);
  \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={line}]
   \draw (identify) edge (evaluate)
    (evaluate) edge (stop1);
  \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect!!!

Comment: Every answer you game me, is a solution for my problem.
thanks again for your response!!!